# Copy multiple webpages source code to txt, C#

Tags: c#

Below is my code. I have multiple webpages, and I need to save all these webpages sources codes to one txt file, is it possible? My code is saving just one webepage source, I can choose which one to save by changing number in that part of code:

```
string s=WebClient.DownloadString(listBox8.Items[0].ToString());
```

In listbox8 there is multiple webpages adresses. Those addresses are taken from tvrage_db2.txt file.

Can you help me?

```
    List<string> link = new List<string>();
    using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader("tvrage_db2.txt"))
    {
        string line;
        //Read and display lines from the file until the end of the file is reached
        while ((line = sr.ReadLine()) != null)
        {
            string line2 = line;
            link.Add(line2);
        }
    }
    listBox8.DataSource = link;

        using (WebClient WebClient = new WebClient())
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < listBox8.Items.Count; i++)
            {
                string s = WebClient.DownloadString(listBox8.Items[0].ToString());
                Clipboard.SetText(s, TextDataFormat.Text);
                string[] lines = { s };
                System.IO.File.WriteAllLines(@"WriteLines.txt", lines);
            }
        }
}
```

**EDIT:**
Problem solved

```
using (WebClient WebClient = new WebClient())
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < listBox8.Items.Count; i++)
            {
                string s = WebClient.DownloadString(listBox8.Items[i].ToString());
                string[] lines = { s };
                System.IO.File.AppendAllText(@"WriteLines.txt", lines[0]);
            }
        }
```

Comment: Replace WriteAllLines with AppendAllLines. Oh and replace 0 with i in the DownloadString method.

Comment: Just out of interest, what use could you possibly have for storing them all in a single txt file? What are you going to do with that file?

Comment: @musefan, archive it on an USB :)

Comment: @AndreiV: But how would you ever re-use it? If you needed to restore it (or something) you would need to parse each page, which could be a pain, wouldn't it be better to have a archive file for each page source? Not that it matters, it's your requirements, you do what you feel is right for you

Comment: @musefan, I don't understand the reason either. I just think it's fun to imagine transferring the code _the old fashion way_.

Comment: I tried to change only 0 with i, then tried to change WriteAllLines with AppendAllLines and got same error message: Requested Clipboard operation did not succeed. Then I deleted that part of code: Clipboard.SetText(s, TextDataFormat.Text), however just last webpage's source code in a list was saved in txt file. Looks like code overwrites txt file.

Comment: I have 271 webpages, and I need to pull out information from all of them and put it into listboxes. When I am doing it directly from website using regex, application freezes. So I am trying to make it faster. Trying to copy all source codes to txt file, and then pull out information which I need. Have no idea if that way of programming will give me what I want :)

Answer (score 0):

You're already looping `listBox8` items, so change

```
string s = WebClient.DownloadString(listBox8.Items[0].ToString());
```

to

```
string s = WebClient.DownloadString(listBox8.Items[i].ToString());
```